# "constructor" functions that are not meant to be used with a constructor call

Tags: javascript, node.js

(full code in [this github repo](https://github.com/mperdikeas/js-object-creation-without-new.git))

In the [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) book series (particularly the "this&Object Prototypes" title) as well as in many SO answers (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631274/274677)) the point is often made that there's no such thing as "constructor functions" but rather ordinary functions that are invoked with a "constructor call". I am trying to grok this point by creating vanilla functions that are not meant to be invoked with `new` to create my objects.

The first attempt works:

```
var assert = function(condition, message) {
    if (!condition)
        throw new Error(message||'assertion error');
};

var Counter1 = function() {
    var count = 0;
    return {get: function() {return count;},
            inc: function() {count++;}};
};

var c2a = Counter1();
c2a.inc();
assert(c2a.get()===1);
var c2b = Counter1();
assert(c2b.get()===0);
assert(c2a.get()===1); // previous counter is a separate object
```

Now I am trying to improve the above code by not re-creating the getter/setter functions every time and instead simply assign them to a prototype (and here's were I fail):

```
var Counter2 = function Counter2_() {
    var count = 0;
    Counter2_.prototype.get = function() {return count;};
    Counter2_.prototype.inc = function() {count++;};
    assert(Counter2_.prototype.constructor === Counter2_);
    var rv = {};
    rv.__proto__ = Counter2_.prototype;
    return rv;
};

var c = Counter2();

c.inc();
assert(c.get()===1);
assert(Object.getPrototypeOf(c)===Counter2.prototype);

var cb = Counter2();
assert(Object.getPrototypeOf(cb)===Counter2.prototype);
assert(cb.get()===0);
assert(c .get()===1, 'expecting c to be 1 but was:'+c.get());
```

The above code fails on the last line.
My understanding is that the above code does not succeed in maintaining separate counters as every time the `Counter2` function is called the prototype `get` of previous objects is set to the newly created function which is lexically bound to a new `count` (initialized to 0 again). **Plus** the code is **stupid** as the functions are again created every time the `Counter2` function is called and reassigned on the prototype over and over again (with the disastrous result that separate counters cannot be maintained).

Yet, trying to place the assignment to the prototype outside the `Counter2` function also fails as the `count` variable is no longer in scope:

```
var Counter3 = function Counter3_() {
    var count = 0;
    var rv = {};
    rv.__proto__ = Counter3_.prototype;
    return rv;
};

Counter3.prototype.get = function() {return count;}; // this fails - I no longer have access to count's lexical scope
Counter3.prototype.get = function() {return this.count;}; // this fails too
```

My questions are:

1) is my reading of why `Counter2` fails to maintain separate counters correct?

2) is there any way to use this idiom (i.e. to employ "vanilla" functions that are not meant to be called with `new`) and yet avoid recreating the getters/setters every time the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yep the prototype's get and inc are redefined each time.  Prototypes not being "closed" and the up the chain behavior of prototypical inheritance makes this possible.

```
function Counter2(name) {
    var count = 0;

    Counter2.prototype.get = function() {return count;};
    Counter2.prototype.inc = function() {count++;};

    var rv = {};
    if(name) {
        rv.get = function() {console.log(name); return count;};
    }
    console.log(count)
    rv.__proto__ = Counter2.prototype;
    return rv;
}

var a = Counter2('a');
var b = Counter2('b');
var c = Counter2();
```

In the following example a and b do not inherit the `get` function because their `get` key is not undefined and points to a different function instance.  Remember the count variable is still getting allocated and uniquely bound if a name is passed in and knowing that the prototypes are being redefined each time you can guess what the output of the following will be.

```
a.inc();a.inc();
[a.get(), b.get(), c.get()]
```

Is :

> [0, 0, 2]

2) Yes and no . You can easily return objects that have functions that do not get allocated every time but if a variable is bound it will be shared between them.  Oddly enough by using prototypical inheritance and the `new` operator this can be done pretty easily.

For example the following code does not allocate a new function every time but `a.inc()` will increment the value for `b` and others if called.

```
var count = 0;

function inc() {++count;}
function get() {return count;}

function Count() {
    return {inc: inc, get: get};
};

var a = Count();
var b = Count();
```

By using the `new` operator a uniquely bound "variable" can be achieved without allocating a new function every time.

```
    function Count(){}
    Count.prototype.count = 0;
    Count.prototype.get = function() {return this.count;};
    Count.prototype.inc = function() {this.count++;};

var a = new Count();
var b = new Count();
a.inc();
a.get();
>>1
b.get();
>>0
a.inc === b.inc
>>true
```