# Why adding a method to JavaScript reference type like this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Let's say I have such constructor:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

And I want to add methods to it.

Why this:

```
Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

Is the way to do it, and not this:

```
Person.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

I have no idea why I am getting downvoted, so I would appreciate if downvoters would add comments with the actual reason of downvote. This will help me phrase my future questions better.

I do understand the inheritance concept behind prototyping to some extent. At least to the extent shown in tutorials, articles and books in beginner level.

What confuses me is probably my background in Java and the class term, which is not the same thing in JavaScript.

I imagine that this defines a class `Person`:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

When I create an object using that class:

```
var myObject = new Person("John", "Doe");
```

I can still add some new properties or methods to that object:

```
myObject.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

Now only `myObject` will have this new method `getFullName`, pretty clear.

```
var myObject2 = new Person("Daniel", "Cook");
```

For `myObject2` there is no `getFullName` method, still clear.

Once I add a method to the prototype of my "class" `Person` it will be inherited by all objects created with that "class":

```
Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

Now even `myObject2`, has the `getFullName` method. Clear.

Ok. I think I am comming to the root of the problem in my head. Extending this post helped me.

The function `Person` is also an object, right?

Comment: I'd check out some JS tutorials that discuss its prototypal inheritance system.

Comment: @DaveNewton I did, but this was still unclear, that's why I asked. Haveing some expereience in Java I'd imagine adding a method to the "class" Person.getfullName would be fine. I haven't seen that in any example, and it doesn't throw any errors so it does something. The question was what exactly and is it usefull.

Comment: I think reading my answer this question will help you (it's not a dup, just related) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630409/what-is-the-point-of-javascript-constructor/31630682#31630682

Comment: @so_user JS doesn't have classes; I'd get over that conceptual hurdle first. An object's prototype is sort of like its class (only sort of); a method added to a prototype will be available to every object whose prototype chain includes the prototype the method is added to. You probably shouldn't try to relate JS OOP-ness to Java OOP-ness; they use very different mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myObject.methodName = function() {};` adds a method named `methodName` to object `myObject`. That means that you can call it directly from the `myObject` and you don't need to create an instance.

To put it simply, you just call it by doing this :

```
myObject.methodName();
```

---

`myObject.prototype.methodName = function() {};` adds a method named `methodName` to the prototype of object `myObject`. That means it exists for every instance of `myObject`, but you cannot call it directly from the `myObject`.

You call it by doing this :

```
var someInstance = new myObject();
someInstance.methodName();
```

In this case, `myObject.methodName();` would generate an error!

---

Both are valid ways to implement an `object` on JavaScript. There's just a different concept behind them.

For a more in depth look into the difference between both approaches, I recommend you take a look at my article [**The many ways to implement OOP in Javascript**](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-many-ways-to-implement-oop-in-javascript-3010423ed6db#.4x1guln90).

Comment: When it comes to adding methods to object itself, or to it's prototype - I understand it. But in the code above, I have added a method to the "class" Person, not the actual object. When a method is added to the class, not instantiated object, that was what confused me.

Comment: I'll get back once I've read your article. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @so_user : Until the recent addition of classes EcmaScript, there are no classes in JavaScript. There's just functions and objects. Anyway, objects (what you call "classes") that aren't initiated behave more or less like a singleton class in Java.